# Spring Boot 2.0 OAuth2 Client - Getting bearer token across sessions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

I have a basic OAuth2 App set up:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Order(0)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health", "/", "/noauth", "/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2Login().defaultSuccessUrl("/auth");
    }
}
```

It works well for a single instance and I can request `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` details:

```java
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
    oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oauthToken.getName());

// Gets an OAuth2 token
client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue()
```

However, if I run this in a microservices environment (>1 instance) then `client` will always be null. Authentication also doesn't work correctly in this case.

I am using the `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose` library and authenticating with Google.

Any hints on how to persist the bearer token between sessions (or refresh it if it's not there)?

Comment: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893795/how-to-persist-oauth2authorizedclient-in-redis-session/61912641#61912641