# How to persist OAuth2AuthorizedClient in redis-session

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

My project uses redis session with springboot session and **spring security 5.1.10**. I just migrated the old oauth2 implementation. Before, when I restarted the app I still had the access_token and refresh_token. With this implementation the user is logged in, but I loose the AuthorizedClients so loadAuthorizedClient function returns null after restarting. Also in production we have many containers with the same app. Is there any springboot stardard way to achieve this? like register some bean or something.

application.yml

```yaml
    ...

    session:
        store-type: redis
        redis:
            namespace: spring:session:${spring.application.name}
    redis:
        host: ${redissession.host}
        password: ${redissession.password}
        port: ${redissession.port}

    security:
        oauth2:
            client:
                registration:
                    biocryptology:
                        provider: example
                        client-id: client
                        client-secret: xxx
                        client-authentication-method: basic
                        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
                        redirect-uri-template: "{baseUrl}/login"
                        scope:
                            - openid
                provider:
                    example:
                        issuer-uri: https://....
    ...
```

Controller.java

```java
        @Autowired
        private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

        @GetMapping("/user")
        public String getOidcUserPrincipal() throws InvalidSessionException {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (!(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser)) {
                throw new InvalidSessionException();
            }

            OidcUser principal = ((OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal());
            LOG.info("oidc: {}", principal.getName());

            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth2Token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            LOG.info("authentication: {}", oauth2Token);
            OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService
                    .loadAuthorizedClient(oauth2Token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication.getName());
            LOG.info("client: {}", client);

            return "logged";

        }
```

The goal is getting the access_token and refresh_token across containers, any other way without OAuth2AuthorizedClientService maybe?

EDIT:

```xml
        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Do you mind listing the exact dependencies and versions here? I tried your solution but it didn't work for me so I wanted to compare the library versions. Thanks.

Comment: @Sun, I edited the post, we use a dependency manager shared between projects, I think those dependencies are enough information. This is the starter security version:
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE
 org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:jar:5.1.10.RELEASE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Registering a bean did the trick, it saves it in session, but then `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` breaks down for every case and needs a workaround searching in session directly or using `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` autowired:

```java
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
    }
```

controller.java

```java
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository clientRepository;

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Map<String, Object> getOidcUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) throws InvalidSessionException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof OidcUser)) {
            throw new InvalidSessionException();
        }

        OidcUser principal = ((OidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal());

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientRepository
                .loadAuthorizedClient(oauth2Token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authentication, request);
        LOG.info("client: {}", client);
        if (Objects.nonNull(client)) {
            String token = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            String refreshtoken = client.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue();

            LOG.info("token: {} {}", token, refreshtoken);
        }

        return principal.getClaims();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. I still didn't understand why I need that method. I provided all needed configurations (apparently) in the application YML.

Comment: What would be your test mechanism to get sure this work ? (In order to be suitable for distributed applications or persisting across restarts)